# Automapper throws System.ArgumentException Method T GetValue[T]() is a generic method definition (Parameter 'method')

Tags: automapper

I am working on a for me rather large blazor web app and use Automapper to simplify mapping. After upgrade to VS 2019 and update to newest nuget packages I get this error:

```
 avsweb.ApplicationTests.Mappings.MappingTests.ShouldHaveValidConfiguration
   Source: MappingTests.cs line 69
   Duration: 1 ms

  Message: 
    System.ArgumentException : Method T GetValue[T]() is a generic method definition (Parameter 'method')
  Stack Trace: 
    Expression.ValidateMethodInfo(MethodInfo method, String paramName)
    Expression.ValidateMethodAndGetParameters(Expression instance, MethodInfo method)
    Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method)
    <>c.<MemberAccesses>b__3_0(Expression inner, MemberInfo getter)
    Enumerable.Aggregate[TSource,TAccumulate](IEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 func)
    ExpressionFactory.MemberAccesses(IEnumerable`1 members, Expression obj)
    TypeMapPlanBuilder.Chain(IMemberMap memberMap, Type destinationType)
    TypeMapPlanBuilder.BuildValueResolverFunc(IMemberMap memberMap, Expression destValueExpr, Expression defaultValue)
    TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreatePropertyMapFunc(IMemberMap memberMap, Expression destination, MemberInfo destinationMember)
    TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateAssignmentFunc(Expression destinationFunc)
    TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateMapperLambda(HashSet`1 typeMapsPath)
    TypeMap.CreateMapperLambda(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, HashSet`1 typeMapsPath)
    TypeMap.Seal(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider)
    MapperConfiguration.Seal()
    MapperConfiguration.ctor(MapperConfigurationExpression configurationExpression)
    <>c.<AddAutoMapperClasses>b__12_2(IServiceProvider sp)
    CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
    CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
    CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
    CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
    CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
    CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
    <>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
    ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
    ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
    ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
    ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
    <>c.<AddAutoMapperClasses>b__12_3(IServiceProvider sp)
    CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
    CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
    CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
    CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
    CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
    <>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
    ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
    ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType)
    ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
    ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
    MappingTests.ctor(ITestOutputHelper _outputHelper) line 65
```

Automapper is registerd using the ServiceCollection Extention. All ValuResolvers are registered through custom service extension.
I have at the moment no glue where  to look at. Does anyone hav a hint?

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming across this post later and "removing the generic method" is not an answer: AutoMapper has a feature to map Pre/PostFixes.

By default it knows the prefix "Get" and tries to map the source method `GetValue[T]()`to the destination property `Value`. However, it doesn't know how to map generic methods by default, thus the mapping fails.

To fix this, there are two options:

- Rename the method to not include the "Get"
- As stated in the documentation below, clear the prefixes using: `cfg.ClearPrefixes()`

This behaviour is defined briefly here:
https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#recognizing-pre-postfixes

Comment: Going forward we will automatically [ignore](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/3920/commits/031964d6428e677ed6e6a04ffe4a7b93b271d3f6) these.

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the reasen for problem. To hande key/value pairs I added following class to project:

```
public class KeyValuePair
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public T GetValue<T>()
        {
            var value = (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromInvariantString(Value);
            return value;
        }
        public void SetValue<T>(T value)
        {
            Value = value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The method GetValue should provide a way to get the string value converted to object of type T. Through some automation process a mapping profile hase been defined for this class. This finally leads to the Argument exception either when validating mapping or when instantiating automapper (IMapper).  I don't know why this error exactly happens, but mapping is for this class not useful anyway. so removing it from profile solved the case.

The hard part of it was to find the failing class out of 50+ classes / dto's. Luckily I create the Automapper profile dynamically during startup from methods in the class definitions. So it was possible to implement a testmethod with xUnit and Memberdata creating a mappingprofile for each single class and verify each single configuration. This did show the failing mappings.
Here a snippet how the map is created:

```
    public partial class SettingDto : IMapperBase<Setting>
    {
        public void MappingBase(Profile profile)
        {
            // Generated Mapping
            profile.CreateMap<Setting, SettingDto>()
                   .IncludeAllDerived()
                   .ForMember(m => m.Id, s => s.MapFrom(id => id.SettingId))
          ;
        }
    }
```

Class Setting derived from KeyValuePair class shown above.
Here a snippet for testing the single map:

```
      [Theory]
        [InlineData(typeof(ReychSettingDto),"MappingBase")]
        public void SingleClassProfileMapperTest(Type type, string method)
        {
            // Arrange
            logger.Information("Processing {@Name}", type.Name);
            var profile = new MappingProfile(type, method) as Profile;
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.AddProfile(profile); });
            // Act

            //Action act = () => config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            //act.Should().Throw<AutoMapperConfigurationException>();
            try
            {
                config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            }
            catch (AutoMapperConfigurationException aex)
            {

                logger.Error(aex, "Config");
            }
            // Assert
        }

        public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetProfiles(Type mapType, string method, int skip, int count)
        {
            var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetName().Name == "avsweb.Application");
            var allObjects = assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i =>
                                    i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == mapType))
                                    .Select(o => new object[] { o, method })
                                    .ToList();

            if (count < 0)
            {
                return allObjects;
            }
            return allObjects.Skip(skip).Take(count);
        }
    }

    public partial class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile(Type type, string method)
        {
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            var methodInfo = type.GetMethod(method);
            methodInfo?.Invoke(instance, new object[] { this });
        }
    }
```

Hopefuly it helps somebody